# (Too simple?) proof that $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This question has been asked several times and the answers given there are not straightforward. The reason I am posting it here is that my solution seems much simpler.

Because I am self-teaching, there is a high probability that I have made an error, and I would like to learn from such an error.

---

**Problem:** Let $A$, $B$ be two subsets of a set $X$, and let $f:X \to Y$ be a function. Show that

$$f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B)$$

**My Solution:**

Let's set out the basics first:

$$x \in A \implies f(x) \in f(A) \tag{i}$$
$$x \in B \implies f(x) \in f(B) \tag{ii}$$

The contrapositive of the second statement will be useful:

$$f(x) \notin f(B) \implies x \notin B \tag {iii}$$

Now we construct the set $f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

- If we set $x \in A$ to be true, then $f(x) \in f(A)$ is true. We want this because it is true of the set $f(A) \setminus f(B)$.
- We also want $f(x) \notin f(B)$ to be true because it is true of the set $f(A) \setminus f(B)$. If this is true, then $x \notin B$ is true.

Collecting things which are true, we have:

- $x \in A$
- $x \notin B$

Thus, $f(x) \in f(A) \setminus f(B) \implies f(x) \in f(A \setminus B)$. That is,

$$f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B) \quad \square$$

Comment: It’s a bit problematic what is $x$ in your argument, since you’re supposed to consider an element of $f(A) \setminus f(B)$, which is a subset of $Y$, rather than an element of $X$. Instead, you should say if $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$, then there exists $x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$. And since $f(x) = y \notin f(B)$, we have $x \notin B$, so $x \in A \setminus B$ and $y = f(x) \in f(A \setminus B)$.

Comment: As expressed by the answer of David K, $~y \in f(A),~$ and $~y = f(x)~$ does not imply that $~x \in A.~$  That is, you could have $~x_1 \in A, ~x_2 \not\in A,~$ such that $~f(x_1) = y = f(x_2).$  Actually, your posted analysis will work, if it is given that $~f~$ is an injection.

Comment: @DavidGao didn't just take an arbitrary $x \in X$ satisfying $y = f(x)$. He picked an $x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$, the existence of which is guaranteed since $y \in f(A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If we set $x \in A$ to be true, then $f(x) \in f(A)$ is true. We want this because it is true of the set $f(A) \setminus f(B).$

We also want $x \in A$ because otherwise $x$ will not be in $A \setminus B.$

But what we "want" to be true cannot be relied upon in this way as part of a proof. After all, we also "want" the theorem to be true.

So in the end, all you have proved is that if $x \in A \setminus B,$ then $f(x) \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ and $f(x) \in f(A \setminus B),$
whereas what you actually needed to prove was that if $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$
then $y \in f(A \setminus B).$

---

But the proof is easily fixed. As has already been explained in comments under the question, you can start with $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ and show that the $x$ that you want actually does exist. Then you can finish and the proof will be valid because you started from an appropriate premise.

Comment: While I agree that @Penelope's proof is worded in a way that is technically incorrect, I think it is also worth pointing out that the line of reasoning is correct, and the proof can be fixed.

Comment: @NaturalLogZ Yes, as demonstrated in a comment. I will add that.

Comment: @DavidK "So in the end, all you have proved is that.." - this is very helpful in correcting my thinking. I will study the comments as I want to truly understand a proof, and not just parrot one of the many that are online. I will mark as 'answered" as you have pointed out my error.