# Show that $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B)$ - difficulty with quantifiers.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm self-teaching and really struggling with this exercise from Terence Tao's Analysis I 4th ed, exercise 3.4.3

I did post about this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842472/too-simple-proof-that-fa-setminus-fb-subseteq-fa-setminus-b) previously to ask where my error was, and my error was pointed out - but I have not since made progress. I apologise for my slow progress, self-teaching without a teacher or mentor means slow progress.

**Exercise:**

> Let $A$, $B$ be two subsets of a set $X$, and let $f:X \to Y$ be a
> function. Show that $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B)$

**Question:** I can follow the solutions posted online but when I try to write one myself I struggle with the logic, and I think my lack of knowledge is related to quantifiers.

---

**My Attempt In Very Small Steps**

I'll take this in small steps so that my error(s) can be isolated.

**Step 1:**

To show $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B)$ we need to show the following implication:

$$y \in f(A) \setminus f(B) \implies y \in f(A \setminus B)$$

**Step 2:**

Our next step is to understand which $x \in X$ relate to $f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

If $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ then **there is an** $x \in A$ such that $f(x) =y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

**Query:** Is this the same as "**for some** $x \in A$"? Why can't we say "**for all** $x \in A$"?

So far we have established that $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A)$, which is not wrong, but doesn't take into account what we're told about $f(B)$.

**Step 3:**

Having established that $x \in A$ is relevant, we now focus on the exclusion of $f(B)$.

**Comment:** This is where I have trouble with quantifiers and logic.

If $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$  then there is an $x \in A$ such that $f(x) =y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ **but also** (logical conjunction)

- Option 1: **there is an** $x \in B$ such that $f(x) = y \notin f(A) \setminus f(B)$
- Option 2: **for all** $x \in B$ we have $f(x) = y \notin f(A) \setminus f(B)$

**Query:** I'm not sure which of these two is right. Intuitively the second feels right, but I can't justify it in words.

**Step 4:**

If Option 1 was correct, we can say: There is an $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ **and** there is an $x \in B$ such that $f(x) = y \notin f(B)$.

This doesn't seem sufficient because it doesn't exclude the possibility of **other** $x \in B$ such that $f(x) =y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

If Option 2 was correct, we can say: There is an $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ **and for all** $x \in B$ we have $f(x) = y \notin f(B)$.

This seems sufficient to exclude all $x \in B$. Then we can say: If $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$  then $x \in A \land x \notin B$ such that $f(x) = y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

**Step 5:**

Continuing Option 2, we have concluded that $x \in A \land x \notin B$.

Under $f$ this maps to $f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

Thus we conclude: if $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ then $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$.

This is equivalent to $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B)$. $\square$

---

I would like to than you for your patience with this.

Comment: Query of the step 2: you cannot say that for every $x \in A$, $f(x) = y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$ because $f: X \to Y$ is not set as a constant function. In your implicit second question of step 2, you can check the second contradiction in the proof.

Comment: For you query in the step 3, note that $y \not \in f(B)$ means that "it does not exists some $x \in B$ such that $f(x) = y$", because if it does, then $y = f(x_0) \in B$ for some $x_0 \in B$ (which is contradicting that $y \not \in f(B)$). But the state "it does not exists some $x \in B$ such that $f(x) = y$" equals to "for all $x \in B$, $f(x) \neq y$". Take a look in Internet for the negation of quantifiers.

Comment: In step 4, when you assume that the option 1 is the correct one, which is not, the first problem is that you are losing generality and the second problem is that you are assuming that the $x_1 \in A$ such that $y = f(x_1) \in f(A)$ is the same $x_2 \in B$ such that $y = f(x_2) \not \in f(B)$.

The reasoning in step 4 for the option 2 is not clear: you are directly assuming that $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$ automatic satisfies that $f(x) \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$, but you only know that $f(x) \in f(A)$. You will find the details for this issue in the first contradiction of the proof I made.

Comment: Step 5 become right when clarifications are made in step 4 as indicated above.

Comment: It's hard to teach insight.  I did this simply: if $w \in f(A)\f(B)$ then $w \in f(A)$ so there is an $a\in A$ so that $f(a) = w$.  But $w\not \in f(B)$ so there is no $b\in B$ so that $f(b)=w$.  That means that $a$ can not be an element of $B$.  So $a \in A$ but $a\not \in B$.  So $a\in A\B$.  And therefore $w= f(a)$ for some $a \in A\B$.  And thus $w \in f(A\B)$.  That's really all. Sadly I can't really teach *why* I thought of this and why it was "obvious" for me.  But I hope with a little practice with just understanding the "language" things will eventually snap.

Comment: "...I apologize for my slow...." No, Penelope that really is not necessary. I congratulate you with the mathematical skills that are gifted with and admire your persevering in exploiting them.

Comment: @BlueTomato thank you for your comments - a key misunderstanding I had was the negation of quantifiers. I will explore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$
- $x\in f(A)$ and $x\notin f(B)$
- $x=f(y)$ for **some** $y\in A$ and $x\neq f(z)$ for **every** $z\in B$.

Now choose some $y_0\in A$ with $x=f(y_0)$ which is possible according to the first part of the third bullet.

Then realize that this chosen $y_0\in A$ cannot be an element of $B$ because this would contradict the second part of the third bullet.

So it can be concluded that the chosen $y_0$ is an element of $A\setminus B$.

Proved is now that $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in A\setminus B$ or equivalently that $x\in f(A\setminus B)$.

This procedure works for **every** $x\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ which allows us to conclude that: $$f(A)\setminus f(B)\subseteq f(A\setminus B)$$

---

For completeness let me rewrite the third bullet applying quantifiers:

- $\exists y\in A[x=f(y)]\text{ and }\forall z\in B[x\neq f(z)]$

Here the second part of the bullet is equivalent with: $$\neg\exists z\in B[x=f(z)]$$

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have marked it as "answered" because you have highlighted the key gap in my knowledge which was the third bullet point.

In fact I fail to grasp the "some" part of the argument. That is, $f(A)$ is the image of $A$ under $f$. So in my mind "every" element of $A$ maps to $f(A)$ under $f$ not "some". Clearly I have another gap in my understanding so will ask a separate question.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845424/why-does-fa-mean-for-some-x-in-a-fx-in-fa-and-not-for-all

Comment: You are very welcome. I see that your separate question has been answered quite well and that you accepted the answer. So I conclude that things are clear now. If not then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A, B \subset X$ and $f: X \to Y$ an arbitrary function. We want to prove that $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subset f(A \setminus B)$.

Let $x \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$. Then, it satisfies two hyptheses:
$$\exists x_0 \in A \quad \text{s.t.} \quad x = f(x_0) \in f(A), \quad (1)$$
and
$$\forall y \in B, \quad f(y) \neq x, \quad (2)$$
To show that $x \in f(A \setminus B)$, it is necessary to show that there is some $z \in A \setminus B$ such that $x = f(z) \in f(A \setminus B)$.

By $(1)$, we can pick $z = x_0$. Then, $z \in A$ and $x = f(z)$. If $z \in B$, by $(2)$, it follows that $f(z) \neq x$, but this contradicts $(1)$, so $z \not \in B$. Therefore, $z \in A\setminus B$.

Now lets see that $x \in f(A \setminus B)$. Lets suppose that $x \not \in f(A \setminus B)$. Thus, for every $y \in A \setminus B$, $f(y) \neq x$. In particular, $z \in A \setminus B$, so $f(z) \neq x$, but it is a contradiction since $f(z) = x$. Therefore, $x \in f(A \setminus B)$ and

$$f(A) \setminus f(B) \subset f(A \setminus B)$$

You have to check the cases in which $A = \emptyset$ or $B = \emptyset$.