# Why does $f(A)$ mean "for some" $x \in A$, $f(x) \in f(A)$, and not "for all" ? (Quantifiers)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This question is about **quantifiers**.

Assume $f:X \to Y$ is a function, with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$.

If $A$ is a subset of $X$ then $f(A)$ is a subset of $Y$.

During many exercises that I am doing (eg Tao Analysis I) many solutions start with the argument:

> If $y \in f(A)$, then for **some** $x \in A$ it is true that $f(x) = y \in f(A)$.

**Question:** I don't understand why "for some" and not "for all".

---

**My thoughts:**

My thinking, which likely has error is as follows:

- $f(A)$ is by definition the image of $A$ under $f$
- that means any and all $x \in A$ map to some element of $f(A)$
- if not all did, then that would mean some $x' \in A$ didn't map to an element of $f(A)$ which would contradict the meaning of $f(A)$

Quantifiers have been a real problem for me as I self-teach, so your patience and simple explanations would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: What does $y >\in A$ mean?  Assuming that's a typo for $\in$, then of course it's only for some $x\in A$...you shouldn't expect every $x\in A$ to satisfy $f(x)=y$ for a fixed value of $y$.

Comment: it was a typo, corrected in edit

Comment: Instead of "for some" you could use "there exists". Thats what the author meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be overthinking it a bit. You are right that $f(A)$ is the image of $A$, so every $x\in A$ maps to some $y\in f(A)$.

If we pick a single element $y\in f(A)$, all we know about it is that $y$ is in the image of $A$ under $f$. That means there is at least one choice of $x\in A$ for which $f(x)=y$. There is no reason to assume that the rest of the elements of $A$ also map to $y$. In fact, this would only be true if $f(A)$ is exactly $\{y\}$.

Note that $x$ and $y$ are used to denote single elements here.

Comment: I was overthinking it, apologies.

Comment: No worries; I found it helpful at first to write things out fully: $f(A)=\{y\in Y: f(x)=y\text{ for some }x\in A\}$ and or $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in B\}$.